# Extract one string between double quotations

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to make a custom polybar module that shows the current active window class, since the default module outputs the window name.

I'm using this command to get the window class:

`xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS`

and getting this output:

`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "kitty", "kitty"`

but the desired output is:

`kitty`

how can i do that?

Comment: Which one of the kitties, the first or the second? No, the "instance" and "class" are not always identical. Also, many windows don't have any `WM_CLASS` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with method

```
xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS| awk '{gsub(/[","]/,"",$3);print $3}'


output

kitty
```

python

output of command "xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS" is saved in variable "a"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
a='"WM_CLASS(STRING) = "kitty", "kitty"'
b=a.split(' ')[2]
print b.replace('"','').replace(",","")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may get away with:

```
xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS | 
    awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
```

But also with (the simpler):

```
xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS | 
    cut -d '"' -f 2
```

Or (warning, if the regex fails to match, the whole input will be printed)

```
xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS | 
    sed 's/^[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

Or, sed again, but a bit more robust:

```
xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS |
    sed -n 's/^[^"]*r"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/p'
```

Or, even (not so robust) with grep (but only GNU grep and with Perl regex):

```
xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) WM_CLASS |
    grep -Po  '^[^"]*"\K[^"]*'
```

Is that what you mean?
In words: extract the string inside the first pair of quotes, fail otherwise ?

Answer (score 1):

`xprop` outputs strings in a very similar format to that of ksh93/zsh/bash's `$'...'` quoting where backslash, control and non-ASCII characters are represented as their ANSI C `\\`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t` or `\ooo` notation.

The only difference is that because they're enclosed in double quotes, `"` itself is rendered as `\"` and `'` rendered as `'` instead of `\'`, so it should not be too difficult to convert that output to `WM_CLASS=$'...'` to be evaluated by the shell.

However it's even easier (and safer) to get `xprop` to output it as hex values, and transform to `$'\xHH...'`:

For the application name (the first `kitty` in your example):

```
eval "$(
  xprop -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" -notype 8x WM_CLASS |
    sed 's/0x/\\x/g;s/[, ]//g;s/\\x0.*/'\''/;s/=/=$'\'/
)"
```

for the application class name (the second `kitty` in your example):

```
eval "$(
  xprop -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)" -notype 8x WM_CLASS |
    sed 's/0x/\\x/g;s/[, ]//g;s/=.*\\x0\(.*\)\\x0/=$'"'\\1'/"
)"
```

Both set the `$WM_CLASS` shell variable.

That would work regardless of what byte value the property may contain.

Assumes a shell with support for `$'\xHH'`.